# Memcache item with any Expiration expires immediately on Google App Engine with Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, memcached

This code snippet:

```
err = memcache.JSON.Set(c, &memcache.Item{
    Key:        mkey,
    Object:     &total,
    Expiration: 600,
})
```

followed by a second call with this:

```
_, err := memcache.JSON.Get(c, mkey, &total);
```

...results in a cache miss.
Simply changing the Expiration value to 0 results in cache hits, but then I can't control when the items expire.

Am I misreading how expiration is supposed to work?

Comment: Did you try a with a greater value than 600? `Time.Duration` (http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) is in nanosecond. Maybe 600 nanoseconds is a bit short.

Comment: @VonC: I don't what package is being used here, but the ones I've seen do set Expiration in seconds, but it is worth checking ;)

Comment: @JimB I was looking at the google appengine memcache item, which does use `Time.Duration`: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/memcache/reference#Item

Comment: @VonC: good point, I didn't notice the app-engine tag. That's probably the issue then.

Comment: The docs say it's specified in seconds, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  time.Second * 600 worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the [memcache.Item](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/memcache/reference#Item) does use [Time.Duration](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) (nanosecond), it is best to specify the `Expiration` field using seconds:

```
 time.Second * 600
```

The memcache doc mentions:

```
// Expiration is the maximum duration that the item will stay
// in the cache.
// The zero value means the Item has no expiration time.
// Subsecond precision is ignored.
// This is not set when getting items.
Expiration time.Duration
```

Comment: The docs state the value is in seconds (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/memcache/)

"The app can provide an expiration time when a value is stored, as either a number of seconds relative to when the value is added, or as an absolute Unix epoch time in the future (a number of seconds from midnight January 1, 1970). ".  You're right that it's in Nanos.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3224681 yes, but the field is in Time.Duration, and does mention "Subsecond precision is ignored": so any value below `time.Second * 1` is likely to *not* work.